# How to make a canvas created image follow the mouse pointer?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.6

In tkinter, python, I'm creating a 'game' which involves an image created by the canvas to follow the mouse pointer. Here's what I've tried:

```
def move(event):
    x = event.x
    y = event.y
    canvas.move(example, x, y)

canvas.tag_bind(example, "<Motion>", move)
```

As you can see, I binded the mouse cursor so that when any motion is detected, the `example` would move to that location. But for some reason, it goes off on its on journey. I'd appreciate some help, so thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `move` command takes an offset, but you're passing it coordinates. If you want it to follow the mouse, use the `coords` method so that you set the coordinates of the image to be the same as the coordinates of the event.

For example:

```
def move(event):
    x = event.x
    y = event.y
    canvas.coords(example, x, y)
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me alot :)